# jQuery and Local Storage unusual behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I am trying to retrieve some items from local storage, and if they are there, reveal some content on the page. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
function loadData()
{       
    var transData = storage.get('TransInfo');

    if(transData != undefined)
    {
        $('#UserName').val(transData[0]);

        if(transData[1] == 'Blue')
        {
            $('#radio-choice-1').attr('checked', true);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#radio-choice-2').attr('checked', true);
        }

        $('#TransNum').val(transData[2]);

        if(transData[3] == 'A')
        {
            $('#radio-choice-1-board').attr('checked', true);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#radio-choice-2-board').attr('checked', true);
        }

        unHideAll();
        return true;
    }
};
```

And when the data is finally loaded, I want to call unHideAll():

```
//THIS FUNCTION FAILS WHEN CALLED!!
function unHideAll()
{
    /*
    $('#radio-choice-1').checkboxradio('enable');
    $('#radio-choice-2').checkboxradio('enable');
    $('#radio-choice-1-board').checkboxradio('enable');
    $('#radio-choice-2-board').checkboxradio('enable');
    $('#TransNum').textinput('enable'); 
    $('#UserContinue').remove();
    $('#nextButton').show();
    */
};
```

The problem I am getting is unHideAll() never gets anywhere. If I put an alert() at the top, it will show, but if I put an alert() at the bottom, it never gets there. Any idea why?

Here is how I am calling the methods:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    clearStorage(); 
    loadData();
    unHide();           
    collectData();
});
```

Any idea why I can't get unHideAll() to do anything? It works in the traditional unHide() method, which I use when there is no local storage yet, but if local storage is present it tends to fail quickly.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here is my local storage code:

```
window.storage = {
    store:localStorage,
    get: function( key ) 
    {
        try
        {
            return JSON.parse(this.store[key]);
        } 
        catch(e) {};

        return undefined;
    },
    set: function( key, value) 
    {
        try
        {
            this.store[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
        } 
        catch(e) {};
    }
};
```

EDIT 2:

And here is some code that works, which is why it's puzzling why it won't work in my new method.

```
//THIS CODE WORKS FLAWLESSLY TO REVEAL ITEMS!!
$('#UserContinue').click(function() 
{
    if($('#UserName').val() == '') 
    {
        alert('Please Enter a User Name First!');
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        User_Name = $('#UserName').val();
        $('#radio-choice-1').checkboxradio('enable');
        $('#radio-choice-2').checkboxradio('enable');
        $('#radio-choice-1-board').checkboxradio('enable');
        $('#radio-choice-2-board').checkboxradio('enable');
        $('#TransNum').textinput('enable'); 
        $('#UserContinue').remove();
        $('#nextButton').show();

        confirm('Welcome ' + User_Name +'!');

        return true;
    }

    return true;
});
```

Which is really weird...

Comment: what is `storage.get('TransInfo')`, I think it should `localStorage.getItem('TransInfo')`

Comment: I'm seconding @thecodeparadox, that's the usual syntax, also log the returned transData to your console, something tells me it's not an array you're getting back, if you're getting anything back at all, are there error messages in your console ?

Comment: I have my own storage method, I'll put it up on here as an Edit

Comment: Also, when I used alert() to log transData, all of the data is there and being added to the page correctly, I just can't unHide the fields.

Comment: Well, what exactly is the `checkboxradio()` and `textinput()` functions doing, are they defined within the right scope, are chainable, and most importantly working ?

Comment: I read somewhere that thoes were the methods for enabling elements, but obviously I was wrong. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code of unHideAll() is completely wrong. You don't have methods like checkboxradio() or textinput(). This is why, when the function is called, an error occurs and produces the behavior you explain.
To enable / disable form elements with jQuery, read the FAQ:
http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_disable.2Fenable_a_form_element.3F

Comment: Good eye, just noticed those myself but did'nt see this answer, but it could be that the OP actually has those methods !

Comment: That's weird, cause I use the exact same methods earlier in the code and they work flawlessly.

Comment: Which libraries are you using ? Only jQuery ?

Comment: I am also using jQuery mobile, which is where I got those methods

Comment: Now we have all we need :) Did you look at the console to see if you have errors when unHideAll() is called ?

Comment: Through firebug? Would that be the console you're referring to?

Comment: I get [16:42:46.213] uncaught exception: cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'enable'

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this:

```
window.storage = {
    store:localStorage,
    get: function( key ) 
    {  
      var ret = this.store.getItem('key');
      if(ret) {
           return JSON.parse(ret);
       }
        return undefined;
    },
    set: function( key, value) 
    { 
        this.store.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }
};
```

**NOTE:**

1. In your `get` function I don't see anything that read the `localStorage`
2. `set` function don't set the data to `localStorage`

Comment: Actually it does get and set the storage, read again! You seem to have a typo, `if(reg)`, what is `reg` ?